# Pointer of array never seg fault?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc

I have something I don't understand.

Here is what I do :

```
float* test = (float*) malloc(4 * sizeof(float) );
```

And then I tried to do

```
test[100] = 1.0;
printf("%f\n",test[100]);
```

And ... It worked...

I was waiting for a segmentation fault, but no and I don't understand why.
I wanted to do this to verify that my array has been correctly allocated.
I really didn't expected that, and maybe I miss something so I searched on the internet, and it seems that everybody get a segfault ...
So I came here to ask.
Thanks

Comment: What you do causes _undefined behavior_, including sometimes not segfaulting...

Comment: To begin with please pick the language you actually program in. C and C++ are two very different languages. Secondly, please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And of course please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Then edit your question to improve it, like for example tell us *why* you expected a crash.

Comment: This question is relevant to both C and C++ though, isn't it?

Comment: To verify if your array was correctly allocated, check `if ( test == NULL )` (or the inverse)

Comment: Some programmer dude sorry that my question isn't asked in the best way, I'm on a train and I have access to the internet only through my cellphone. Actually my question concern C and C++, that's why I tagged them both. I use g++ with a .cpp file, but I mostly write C code in it. The rest of my code isn't relevant to my question, the only thing I do to test this behavior is what I wrote here. I malloc an array of 4 float and then ask for the 100th float and that's why I expected a seg fault.

Comment: There is no different snippet, it is the same code and the same variables. Test is a pointer on a float array wich is allocated with my malloc to 4*sizeof(float) which means it is an array of 4.

Comment: I'm very sorry, it seems I totally misread it. But for future questions ***please*** create a proper MSCE to show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you caused is undefined behavior - in this case, it works as expected, but it's a terrible idea to rely on it in any way: compiler optimizations or changing the operating system might suddenly cause "weird" behavior. You should read more on this topic, though in a nutshell, with undefined behavior, the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants.

I don't have enough knowledge to be sure, but I hypothesize that your Operating System prepared a whole memory page for your program. In Linux by default it is 4 KiB, and you accessed bytes up to 400, so there is still plenty of room. Thus, you might be accessing memory that is allocated for your program, as the operating system works with memory blocks not smaller than 4 KiB.

Comment: tehftw Thanks it help me to understand a little bit more, I am curious to know exactly how this work and why it is an undefined behavior as we are talking about a simple array but I think I pretty much got why I don't got a segfault then.

Comment: @Celhim "we are talking about a simple array" there is no array in your code. "I am curious to know exactly how this work and why it is an undefined behavior" How what works? With `test[100] = foo;` you are trying to write to memory that doesn't belong to your program. In fact the memory location `test + 100` (or: `(char*)test + 100 * sizeof(float)`) could be anywhere but you have no business reading from or writing to that memory location.

Comment: @Celhim Also, in C don't cast the result of `malloc()`, in C++ use a `std::vector<>` (or `new`/`new[]` if you are a masochistic personality).